# kableExtra: Adjust length of column label for dynamic column lengths

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

Using R Markdown, I'm creating PDF file which includes a summary table with a dynamically changing/unknown number of  monthly columns. I'd like the "Month Actuals" label to adjust dynamically to appear above all month columns present at the time the report is run.

I created a month_count object:

```
library(tidyverse)
month_count <-
  data %>% 
  summarize(month_count = n_distinct(year_month)) %>% 
  as_vector()
```

and used in the add_header_above function:

```
summary %>%
  kbl("latex", 
      booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(position = "left",
                latex_options = c("HOLD_position",
                                  "scale_down",
                                  "striped")) %>% 
  column_spec(column = 1, width = "2in") %>% 
  column_spec(column = 2:99, width = ".75in") %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Year-to-Date" = 4, "Month-to-Date" = 3, "Monthly Actuals" = month_code))
```

This works, however, the label on the output reads "Monthly Actuals.month_count." Any thoughts on how either to 1) improve this label or 2) set dynamically adjusting header labels?

Below is are the data in play if that is useful information for troubleshooting labeling:

```
data 
 year_month
  <chr>     
2021_07   
2021_08   
2021_09   
2021_10
2021_11   
2021_12   
2022_01   
2022_02

summary
` Area    `Yearly Target` `YTD Total` `Percent of Yearly T~` Balance `Monthly Target` `Current Month~` `Percent of Mo~` `2021 07` `2021 08`
   <chr>             <dbl>       <dbl>                  <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
Area 1              416           0                    0      -416               35                0              0           0         0
Area 2              520          69                   13.3    -451               44                9             20.4        12        11
Area 3              624           0                    0      -624               52                0              0           0         0
 Area 4               50          45                   90        -5                5                7            140           5         3
Area 5                0        6713                    0         0                0              959              0           0      1097
Area 6                0         240                    0         0                0               30              0          21        42
Area 7              125           6                    4.8    -119               11                2             18.2         1         2
Area 8              120          18                   15      -102               10                5             50           0         0
Area 9             3900        1127                   28.9   -2773              325              141             43.4        71        96
Area 10              54           0                    0       -54                5                0              0           0         0
Area 11               0         118                    0         0                0               15              0          50        35
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please make your question reproducible: include the output of `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data, n = 10))` or some other number of rows so that the question can be explored in a meaningful  way to verify a solution. [Link for guidance on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `summary` is the the source tibble/data frame. Variables include Area, Yearly Target, YTD Total , Percent of Yearly Target, Balance, Monthly Target, Current Monthly Average, Percent of Monthly Target, 2021 07, 2021 08,  2021 09, 2021 10, 2021 11, 2021 12, 2022 01, 2022 02

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information, so the question is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `month_count` is a named integer, and that name ends up in the header.

```
> str(month_count)
 Named int 8
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "month_count"
```

Two examples on how to resolve this

- remove the name attribute, `names(month_count) <- NULL` and keep everything else as is
- don't use the `month_count` at all and rely on `ncol(summary)` instead:  `add_header_above(c(" ", "Year-to-Date" = 4, "Month-to-Date" = 3, "Monthly Actuals" = ncol(summary)-8))`

With either of these,the additional text in the header is removed:

[image: before]          ......   [image: after]

Comment: Thank you, pholzm, for your explanation and  solutions. The explancol(summary) option is perfect.